# Micronaut: how to set an HttpClient URL after injection

Tags: java, micronaut

I have the following method:

```
    public HttpResponse<String> sendMessage(@NonNull String url, @NonNull String message) {
            try (HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(new URL(url))) { ... }
    }
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is to create the HttpClient with a URL that comes as a parameter to the method. It cannot be a property in a config file since it depends on some external conditions.
If I check the docs for the HttpClient.create() method it says that it should not be used within a Micronaut environment, and that the client should be injected instead. However, the problem is that if it's injected I cannot initialize it with my custom URL.

Another problem is that if I keep it with the HttpClient.create() method, if I want to unit test the class, I cannot mock the HttpClient. The best option would be to inject it via constructor to be able to create the tests.

What options do I have? I haven't been able to find this type of initialization. It looks like everyone uses a fix URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer it myself. Apparently, you can specify in the request passed to the `HttpClient` methods (retrieve, exchange, etc.) both the relative and full URLs. So it doesn't matter what you put when you inject, instantiate the client.